# App crash (Signal 13) while creating input pipe in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, crash

My app got crash with error **Terminated due to signal 13**.

I am creating input pipe and on that line app got crash with above reason.

```
 public func openConsolePipe() {

        inputPipe = Pipe()

        outputPipe = Pipe()
        let pipeReadHandle = inputPipe.fileHandleForReading

        dup2(STDOUT_FILENO, outputPipe.fileHandleForWriting.fileDescriptor)
        dup2(STDERR_FILENO, outputPipe.fileHandleForWriting.fileDescriptor)

        dup2(inputPipe.fileHandleForWriting.fileDescriptor, STDOUT_FILENO)
        dup2(inputPipe.fileHandleForWriting.fileDescriptor, STDERR_FILENO)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.handlePipeNotification), name: FileHandle.readCompletionNotification, object: pipeReadHandle)

        pipeReadHandle.readInBackgroundAndNotify()
}
```

I am following [This Link](https://medium.com/@thesaadismail/eavesdropping-on-swifts-print-statements-57f0215efb42) for implement this.

Now above tutorial working fine in regular project.

But I am creating framework of this demo and use it another app code.

At that time app got crash on Line.

> dup2(inputPipe.fileHandleForWriting.fileDescriptor, STDERR_FILENO)

This is below method in that I am getting all logs from pipe.

```
@objc func handlePipeNotification(notification: Notification)
{
        inputPipe.fileHandleForReading.readInBackgroundAndNotify()

        if let data = notification.userInfo![NSFileHandleNotificationDataItem] as? Data,
        let str = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii) {

            outputPipe.fileHandleForWriting.write(data)
        }
}
```

Comment: Any error message in console?

Comment: @Larme This is the only message i am getting every time "Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 13"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have founded issue after too much R&D and testing.

Here my app crash because of when i am implement pipe() in library and import that library it's crash because of Pipe() always have to run on Main Queue.

So here i simply create pipe() and all method in Main Queue like this.

```
public func openConsolePipe() {
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        inputPipe = Pipe()

        outputPipe = Pipe()
        let pipeReadHandle = inputPipe.fileHandleForReading

        dup2(STDOUT_FILENO, outputPipe.fileHandleForWriting.fileDescriptor)
        dup2(STDERR_FILENO, outputPipe.fileHandleForWriting.fileDescriptor)

        dup2(inputPipe.fileHandleForWriting.fileDescriptor, STDOUT_FILENO)
        dup2(inputPipe.fileHandleForWriting.fileDescriptor, STDERR_FILENO)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.handlePipeNotification), name: FileHandle.readCompletionNotification, object: pipeReadHandle)

        pipeReadHandle.readInBackgroundAndNotify()
}
}
```

And this is pipe handler method with main Queue.

```
@objc func handlePipeNotification(notification: Notification)
{
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        inputPipe.fileHandleForReading.readInBackgroundAndNotify()

        if let data = notification.userInfo![NSFileHandleNotificationDataItem] as? Data,
        let str = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii) {

            outputPipe.fileHandleForWriting.write(data)
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: I wish I had seen this post earlier.
I was getting the same error for the flutter app, the reason being heavy operation at the very beginning of the app, exactly at the launch of Splash screen. The issue was gone as soon as I removed that code from the beginning.

Comment: I have done too much research for this and finally got this solution. it's not available any where.